# Wordpress CPT and adding a user using ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have been stuck on this for days now, so any advice is really appreciated. I am using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) on a CPT (custom post type).

I have a CPT set up called 'People', and upon adding a 'person', I am trying to add that person as a user upon publishing too. My CPT all works well, and this is what I have got so far using `add_filter` and `wp_insert_user`.

```
add_filter('publish_people', 'people_postdata', 100);
function people_postdata($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $firstname = get_post_meta($post_id, 'first_name', true);
    $lastname = get_post_meta($post_id, 'last_name', true);
    $email = get_post_meta($post_id, 'email_address', true);
    $password = get_post_meta($post_id, 'password', true);
    $username = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', strtolower(get_the_title($post_id)));
    $userargs = array(
        'first_name' => $firstname,
        'last_name' => $lastname,
        'user_login' => $username,
        'user_email' => $email,
        'user_pass' => $password,
        'role' => 'basic'
    );
    // var_dump($userargs);
    wp_insert_user($userargs);
}
```

Now, if I replace `$post_id` with a real post ID, it all works perfectly. But, using `$post_id` to dynamically get the ID of the post I just submitted, it fails to work and leaves first_name, last_name, user_email and user_pass as blank. However, for some reason, user_login works.

When I add in `var_dump($userargs)` to see what it's pulled, it outputs this:

`array(6) { ["first_name"]=> string(0) "" ["last_name"]=> string(0) "" ["user_login"]=> string(11) "richardcook" ["user_email"]=> string(0) "" ["user_pass"]=> string(0) "" ["role"]=> string(5) "basic" }`

I have tried using `get_the_ID()`, and `get_field` but they all have the same result.

Any ideas? I find it odd that it works on `get_the_title` but nothing else. Also, if I `var_dump($post_id)` it brings back the right ID... but is not using it!

Any help is really, really appreciated and anything else you need just let me know.

Many thanks,
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many days, I managed to solve this.

Because I am using ACF, I should use the built-in action to do what you want after the data is saved.

Because this action will be called every time a post is created/saved, etc, I will probably need to add an if statement to check if it's the post type you're looking for.

All of the fields should be available via `$_POST['fields']` as well if get_post_meta does not return what I'm looking for.

The modified code below uses the ACF action **AFTER** the post has been saved, so the meta should be available. I can do a var_dump on the `$_POST['fields']` to see what POST data is available as well.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/actions/acfsave_post/

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'people_postdata', 20);
function people_postdata($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $firstname = get_post_meta($post_id, 'first_name', true);
    $lastname = get_post_meta($post_id, 'last_name', true);
    $email = get_post_meta($post_id, 'email_address', true);
    $password = get_post_meta($post_id, 'password', true);
    $username = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', strtolower(get_the_title($post_id)));
    $userargs = array(
        'first_name' => $firstname,
        'last_name' => $lastname,
        'user_login' => $username,
        'user_email' => $email,
        'user_pass' => $password,
        'role' => 'basic'
    );
    // var_dump($userargs);
    wp_insert_user($userargs);
}
```